# mysql speicific select with order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have table `products` with column `price`.
It have rows with values:

```
2
0
4
5
0
3
1
```

What params with `select` should I use to get result like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
0
0
```

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM products WHERE ... ORDER BY price`

Comment: order by `col_name` asc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could first order by 0 & then rest

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY CASE WHEN price = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,price
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from products
order by price = 0, price
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY IF(price=0,999999999,price)
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98f02/2